# *ngFor with two way binding in IONIC 2

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a page with a button, that when is pressed, it shows a modal that contains a checkbox list. When this modal is closed, it returns the items that was checked, and I want to make a new badge for every returned item in the original page.

I was trying with *ngFor, but is not working, because the "tags" was loaded after this page was loaded.

So my question is, how can I make a "*ngFor" that automatically refresh the interface when the model changes? Something like two way binding.

This is my html code:

```
<button ion-item detail-push (click)="showTagsDialog()">
    <div style="float:left; width:100%; display:block; margin-left:-10px;">
        <button ion-button style="float:left; font-size:1.2rem !important; color:#999; float:left; display:block; text-transform: capitalize;" clear>
            Tags                    
        </button>
    </div>            
    <ion-badge *ngFor="let tag of tags">{{tag.name}}</ion-badge>    
</button>
```

EDIT: I return the selected items when modal   page is closed, using observable pattern, like this:

```
dismiss() {
    this.events.publish(EventIndex.onTagsModalClose, this.dataset.filter(x => { return x.isSelected==true }));
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
}
```

And I recibe like this:

```
private onTagsModalClose(args: any) {        
    this.tags = args;
    this.hasSelectedTags = (<any[]>args).length > 0;
    console.log(this.tags);
}
```

In the console, it shows the items correctly

Comment: How are you returning the new tags from the dialog??

Comment: I return the selected items using observable pattern. I added the code that I'm using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

In your class declare tags as a BehaviorSubject

```
tags : BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject([]);
```

When you recieve the new tags you must emit the new value

```
private onTagsModalClose(args: any) {        
    this.tags.next(args);
    this.hasSelectedTags = (<any[]>args).length > 0;
    console.log(args);
}
```

And in your template subcribe to it with the async pipe

```
<button ion-item detail-push (click)="showTagsDialog()">
    <div style="float:left; width:100%; display:block; margin-left:-10px;">
        <button ion-button style="float:left; font-size:1.2rem !important; color:#999; float:left; display:block; text-transform: capitalize;" clear>
            Tags                    
        </button>
    </div>            
    <ion-badge *ngFor="let tag of tags | async">{{tag?.name}}</ion-badge>    
</button>
```

Comment: It's still not working. I defined it like this: tags: BehaviorSubject<{ id:number, name:string }[]>; 

And to test it, I initialize it like this: this.tags = new BehaviorSubject<{ id:number, name:string }[]>([{ id:1, name:'test' }]);

It shows the "test" badge, but it shows nothing when modal is closed.

Comment: and did you add the async pipe?

Comment: Yes, like this: <ion-badge *ngFor="let tag of tags | async">{{tag?.name}}</ion-badge>

Comment: should be like this [gist](https://gist.github.com/vigohe/e07cabc69e2812a929bd9090cc223953)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133496/discussion-between-victor-godoy-and-vladimir-venegas).